# url locale using django 1.4

Tags: django, localization

Am trying to apply django URL locale as described in here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns

below is my setting file

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

gettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ar', gettext('Arabic')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
```

my urls.py is as following

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns



admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'sitemap.view', name='sitemap_xml'),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',

    url(r'^', include('bon_app.apps.bonz.urls')),

    url(r'^', include('bon_app.apps.pages.urls')),

)
```

it is currently working only for english, when i try 127.0.0.1/en/ it works but when i try  127.0.0.1//ar/ it doesn't any idea why this is happening?

am currently using django 1.4

UPDATE

bon_app/apps/bonz/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('bon_app.apps.bonz.views',

    url(r'^$',              'home',                               name='bonz-home'),
    url(r'^promotion/$',    'home',  {'model'   : 'Promotion'},   name='bonz-promo'),
    url(r'^event/$',        'home',  {'model'   : 'Event'},       name='bonz-event'),
    url(r'^directory/$',    'directory',                          name='bonz-directory')
)
```

bon_app/apps/pages/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('bon_app.apps.pages.views',

    url(r'^contact-us/$', 'contact_us', name='pages-contactus'),
    url(r'^about-us/$', 'about_us', name='pages-aboutus'),

)
```

Comment: Can you please show the code from bonz.urls and pages.urls?

Comment: Hi Jingo, I just updated the question with the code from bonz.urls and pages.urls

Comment: Do you have LocaleMiddleware added to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES?

Comment: Thanks Anna, it was the middleware i missed. Please post it as an answer so i can assign you the bounty points.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> it is currently working only for english, when i try 127.0.0.1/en/ it works but when i try 127.0.0.1//ar/ it doesn't any idea why this is happening?

there you have a double slash "//" before "ar" instead of one slash "/".

maybe that's already the problem?

Comment: ok, please don't vote down, it was just an idea and i tried to help... I think the idea was good, cause sometimes such a small typo makes the difference, and i found it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add LocaleMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES